# in Fullcalendar is there a way to fix the header to not be scrollable

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I seem to recall that there was an option to set the fullcalendar header to always remain visible when you scroll the rest of the calendar, but I can't seem to find the reference any more. Was it my imagination or was this feature available in an earlier release of fc?

Comment: I have annswer for you here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969355/fullcalendar-making-headers-fixed/22247988#22247988

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, I think you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: yes, I believe that you are correct for the month view. However, for week and day view, the desired behavior is already there. I'm just trying to figure out why the month view does not allow you to anchor the header when you resize the window. I will take another pass through the documentation to make sure that I have not missed something. All in all, I am very impressed with Adam Shaw's efforts.